# Who are the top 10 youngest players to reach a FIDE standard rating of 2200?

Tags: rating, statistics, records

In age order of achieving the rating, who are the 10 youngest players to reach 2200 standard FIDE rating? Prag and Karjakin obviously feature, but who else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image: Top 10 Youngest players according to Chess by Numbers]

Chess by numbers posted this on twitter earlier today: https://twitter.com/ChessNumbers/status/1638634335480995841

Comment: woah. this was great.